# How do I run a cronjob on a display?

Tags: xorg, cron

I've added the (f)cronjob

```
*/1 * * * * DISPLAY=:0 notify-send testing
```

to display a notification every minute, but it doesn't work; why not?
(Using i3.)

Comment: Have you checked your environment? The `$DISPLAY` could be `:0.0`.

Comment: @KenSharp, I have.  Also, the same command works if I enter it from another tty.

Comment: As what user does this cronjob run? I do believe that root is by default not allowed to use an x-session from a cronjob

Comment: @Pelle, running as same user that is logged in to x.

Comment: Very likely an authorization issue. `man xauth`, and find out how your desktop system/display manager generates MIT cookies (Gnome does some icky things IIRC). `ps axu | grep X` looking at `-auth` in the commandline if present may be helpful.

Comment: I agree with dirkt, the cronjob works for me but I vaguely recall doing something with xauth for another script a long time ago

Comment: I would recommend putting that in a small script and telling cron to run the script. Not sure why but that has worked for me in the past.

Comment: I should add that I solved this simply by putting `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=<...>` at the top of my cron file.  Works after reboot too on my system.

Comment: @Toothrot You can add that as answer.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work as a cronjob because crontab runs in background. You need to set the variable for it, like this:

```
*/1 * * * * <user> export DISPLAY=:0 && notify-send 'testing'
```

Comment: This doesn't work either.

Comment: Crontab is running in the background, and it doesn't show anything because there's no graphic output specified. You can specify it by adding `export DISPLAY=:0` in your crontab entry (of course assuming `DISPLAY:=0` is the correct display, but you pointed that out in a comment to your question).

Comment: You have added `export` which it seems makes the var available to sub-processes, but that doesn't seem to be the crucial thing here.

Comment: I think you also need to specify an user which is able to log in to x.

Comment: Adding `export DISPLAY=:0` to my cron file actually helped with **Error: GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays**, thanks!