# Crontab addition not working

Tags: cron

I have gone through many answers as to how to add a crontab through terminal through one liners and came across only one single option everywhere which is

```
{crontab -l; echo "1 * * * * /usr/bin/firefox" } | crontab -
```

Running which all I am receiving is

```
>
```

That's it. A promt for me to type something.

and second option being

```
(crontab -l; echo "1 * * * * /usr/bin/firefox" ) | crontab -
```

Which seems to add the cron to `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root` but does not open `firefox` every minute, in fact it does not open at all.

I read most on most answers that you should not edit the `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root` or `/etc/crontab` files directly.

Is this not supported in my system or what?

An output of `uname -a` gave the following description of my system

```
Linux earth 4.9.0-kali4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.30-2kali1 (2017-06-22) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**EDIT: Following message logs are repeated often in my `/var/spool/mail/mail` logs**

> ```
> From root@localhost.localdomain Sun Jul 09 16:01:12 2017 
> Return-path: < root@localhost.localdomain > 
> Envelope-to: root@localhost.localdomain 
> Delivery-date: Sun, 09 Jul 2017 16:01:12 +0530 
> Received: from root by earth with local (Exim 4.89)   
>     (envelope-from <root@localhost.localdomain>)  
>     id 1dU9UY-0001Ry-3A   
>     for root@localhost.localdomain; Sun, 09 Jul 2017 16:01:06 +0530 
> From: root@localhost.localdomain (Cron Daemon) 
> To: root@localhost.localdomain 
> Subject: Cron <root@earth> /usr/bin/firefox 
> MIME-Version: 1.0 
> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit X-Cron-Env: < SHELL=/bin/sh > 
> X-Cron-Env: < HOME=/root > 
> X-Cron-Env: < PATH=/usr/bin:/bin > 
> X-Cron-Env: < LOGNAME=root > Message-Id: < E1dU9UY-0001Ry-3A@earth > 
> Date: Sun, 09 Jul 2017 16:01:06 +0530
>
> Error: GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your second attempt is correct, but your expectation is wrong.

Let's look at it in parts:

```
crontab -l
```

lists all existing entries for the current user's crontab. The

```
echo "1 * * * * /usr/bin/firefox"
```

just prints that line again. These two commands are then grouped together in a subshell and the common output is piped into

```
crontab -
```

So the crontab is overwritten by what comes in via the standard input, which in this case is the old crontab plus the new entry.

As you said it is added to the crontab file. And, assuming the cron daemon is running, the command will be executed each minute.

So why aren't you seeing a firefox window each minute? - Because the conrjob runs in a different shell below the cron daemon, which doesn't have access to your X session, thus firefox will fail and report something like

```
(firefox:22376): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Error: GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays
```

And terminate. How to see that error? Typically the cron daemon will try to send you a mail, see `/var/spool/mail` eventually.

---

About the two forms:

```
{ crontab -l; echo "1 * * * * /usr/bin/firefox" } | crontab -
```

would have to be written as

```
{ crontab -l; echo "1 * * * * /usr/bin/firefox"; } | crontab -
```

(mind the extra semicolon)

The difference between `()` and `{}` is that the former creates a sub-shell, whereas the later executes the commands in the same shell context. Thus variable assignments survive in one form, not in the other.

Comment: I don't know, it adds `1 * * * * /usr/bin/firefox` to `/var/spool/cron/crontab/root` but it just doesn't start firefox. Had a look on `service cron status`. it is running too. It does not add this to `/etc/crontab` although, if that is important.

Comment: I'm quite sure it starts firefox, but firefox doesn't find a display it can use. Check your logs and mail (i.e. in `/var/spool/mail`)

Comment: yes there is an error `Error: GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays` repeated so many times in my logs, check the question above, I have updated it with the error. What do I do?

Comment: What's your actual goal? Adding cron entries works.

Comment: I have my large data uploaded to mega.nz website which requires users to open its website at least once in 2 months or else they'd assume the account inactive and delete the data. So, I want Firefox to open mega.nz once every 2 weeks (in order to be on safe side). So can cron have access to X by any chance? If not, how can I achieve this?

Comment: This sounds like a job for curl or wget or maybe some short scripting ... but too broad for this site

Comment: Hi again @johannes , I found the solution, so thought it might be helpful to you and others to mention here. Yes you were right, the cron is running but cron does not have access to X sessions. I simply added this line to my cron and it worked. `1 1 * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && xhost local:$USER && /usr/bin/firefox`  so now it works perfect. Found my solution from this link with your help. https://serverfault.com/questions/280558/need-with-crontab-and-gui-python-popup Thank you so much..

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when trying to have `firefox-esr` launched from a cron job.

[Setting `DISPLAY` right inside the cron file has helped though](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/348113/how-do-i-run-a-cronjob-on-a-display/348114#348114):

```
* * * * * pi export DISPLAY=:0 && /usr/bin/firefox-esr &
```

(Make sure to figure out your actual `DISPLAY` number by doing `echo $DISPLAY`)